# how to store and display images in other directory in php apache2 in laravel 3

Tags: php, file-upload, apache2, ubuntu-12.04, laravel-3

my directory structure is like (in ubuntu)

```
  /var/www/mysite/application/(here is code)
```

i want to store my uploaded photos in

```
  /var/www/mysite/uploads/(a.jpg)
```

should i use alias in .htacccess file for directory so that it will not expose to other users, where actually directory resides ? but in that case how to display that file in

i refer other Question they said i should use

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
 readfile('/path/to/picture/outside/doc/root/file.jpg');
```

can you gus plz tell me how to store photos in above mentioned directory structure ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends where is your public folder. If it is the ..../my site/ then just in the config folder set the images folder to be the uploads or use URL::to_asset to point to the specific file. could you tell me where is your public folder of Laravel?

Another - exotic - solution would be to use a "proxy" route that would return the requested image via code.

Comment: my directory structure is like /var/www/mysite/siteapp/public and for photos it is /var/www/mysite/uploads/photos/(a.jpg) i want to keep user data seperate, thats why i am not using url::to_asset because it will give me path of public and my photos is in /uploads/photos/ can you tell more about proxy route ?

Comment: Since your data are out of the public folder they are hidden from the visitors. So you could create a controller with an action that returns the image file contents along with the proper headers as you already have read. Though you could use a more laravel-like command like: `return Response::make('Hello World!', 200, $headers);` where you should replace the 'hello world' with the image content.

Comment: because in public folder visitor can view each and every photo of other users..but in my current directory structure also user can see any photo from url in browser , as you said i check for "response::make" and  got this http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=18263 but i dont get it, can you please tell me in more detail ? .in my site there is list of mobiles user have registerd for sale so in response::make how can we pass images of mobiles? and where should i store ? my current directory structure is okay ?

Comment: i got this doc but i did not get it how to pass iamge   http://laravel.io/topic/13/laravels-response-class plz look at  this    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823658/how-securely-store-users-data-in-laravel-3-in-ubuntu-server